Morse Homology: any smooth map $f:S^k\times S^l\to S^{k+l}$ induces the trivial homomorphism on the homologys
I have the following question that i might be asked in my Morse Homolgy exam:

Show that any smooth map $f : S^k \times S^l → S^{k+l}$ induces the zero homomorphism $HM_{k+l}(S^k \times S^l; \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \to HM_{k+l}(S^{k+l}; \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ for $k, l > 0$.

I know how to prove this in the kontext of algebraic topology using the cap product, but I am supposed to use Morse Homology.
Both Homology groups are of course isomophic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ so the map is either the zero map or the identity.
Using the definition of the induced map on the Homologies seems to be too complicated since the construction uses the fact that the map
$$S^k\times S^l\stackrel{f}{\to} S^{k+l} = S^{k+l}\times {0} \subset S^{k+l} \times D^N$$
is homotopic to an embedding, and finding such an embedding for any $f$ seems too difficult.
Instead it seems to me that there must be some kind of trick similar to the cap product where showing that since both induced maps $HM_{k}(S^k \times S^l; \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \to HM_{k}(S^{k+l}; \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ and $HM_{l}(S^k \times S^l; \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \to HM_{l}(S^{k+l}; \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ are zero the same has to be true for the map of index $k+l$, but i don't see how to show this. Is there a statement that the Künneth formula makes about the induced map? I wouldn't know of any other tools i could use in this case.
Can somebody give me a hint on how to do this?
*I saw something on the cap product of Morse cohomology but we did not talk about any of this in the lecture so I will not be allowed to use this in the exam.

I think you misstated the problem and the map should be in the opposite direction: Every nonempty connected compact $n$-dimensional manifolds admits a map to $S^n$ which induces an isomorphism of the top-dimensional mod 2 homology groups.

Nope, I coppied the question word by word and it indeed makes a statement about every possible smooth map: $S^k\times S^l\to S^{k+l}$. The statement that we are supposed to prove is also true which as I said can be done with the cup product. The only question is how to prove it using Morse theory

Then whoever wrote the assignment is wrong and you should complain.
